# remove the space between divs or tiling divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show some div's in HTML page which are tiled automatically without any gaps between them. How can i achieve this, please give your suggestions. Also i want the div's to be adjust automatically after removing some divs using close button.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="main" id="1">
    <p>This is sample test</p>
    <a href="javascript:close('1')">Close</a>
</div>
<div class=" main " id="2">
    <p>This is some sample text which is longer than the other div's and I want other divs to automatically arrange around this wihout space</p>
    <a href="javascript:close(2)">Close</a>

</div>
<div class="main" id="3">
    <h3>I want to move this div UP and remove space below this div</h3> 
    <a href="javascript:close(3)">Close</a>
</div>
<div class=" main " id="4">
    <p>This is sample test</p>
    <a href="javascript:close(4)">Close</a>

</div>
<div class="main" id="5">
    <p>This is sample test</p> <a href="javascript:close(5)">Close</a>

</div>
<div class=" main " id="6">
    <p>This is sample test</p>
    <a href="javascript:close(6)">Close</a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    border: 3px coral solid;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function close(id) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#" + id).remove();
    });
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Bc7tU/1/

Comment: if you dont want gaps remove the margin.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thats not what the OP wants. If you look at the jsfiddle he mentions what he wants.

Comment: Then that should have been explained in the actual question not the html content. @Rams if you want even columns/rows you need to set width and height so that they all have same width height.

Comment: You might get what you're looking for out of [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: yes, I want to show as 2 columns! Please have a look at fiddle link and expand the result window..

Comment: @jmeas I am trying to apply masonry for the same example with no success. can you please help me if you are aware of masonry. You can write the code at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc7tU/1/) and click update

Answer (score 0):

you should add this to your css:

```
.main:nth-child(2n+1) {
     clear: left;   
}
```

Comment: not sure what it will do, but i tried it at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc7tU/1/) and its not working as expected. Thanks for reply.

Comment: you just wanted to get rid of vertical spaces or what? that code snippet removes left floating on each odd element so it removes vertical spacing between them. It's impossible to do what you want that they would stick without any spacing around as long as their height differs between them. Only way to achieve that is using css3 column layout (very poor support in browsers) or you should use javascript to recalculate grid (eg. jQuery Masonry plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Remove/reduce the margin and assign fixed height to give tiles effect to your HTML

Try with

```
 .main {
position: relative;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
float: left;
width: 40%;
border: 3px coral solid;
margin: 2px;
height:150px;
```

}

Comment: I dont want to mention the height as the content of the divs are dynamic in my case.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
.main {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    border: 3px coral solid;
    clear:left
}
```

Comment: I want to show them in 2 columns! So using clear is not working. have a look at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc7tU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.main {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    clear:both;
    border: 3px coral solid;
    margin: 0px;
}
```